# how to set active class on elements

Tags: angular, angular7

I have a problem with setting active class on some elements. Here is some code:

```
<div *ngIf="project">
  <jhi-alert-error></jhi-alert-error>

  <div class="card mb-4">
    <ul class="top-tabs">
      <li>
        <a href="#" [routerLink]="['../', project.id]" [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : ''" (click)="activeMenu($event)">
          <span jhiTranslate="khanbankCpmsApp.project.projectDetail">Төслийн мэдээлэл</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" [routerLink]="['cost-estimate']" [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : ''" (click)="activeMenu($event)">
          <span jhiTranslate="khanbankCpmsApp.project.projectCostEstimateTitle">ТӨСӨВТ ӨРТӨГ</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" [routerLink]="['engineer-assessment']" [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : ''" (click)="activeMenu($event)">
          <span jhiTranslate="khanbankCpmsApp.project.engineerAssessmentTitle">ТӨСӨВТ ӨРТӨГ</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" [routerLink]="['grant']" [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : ''" (click)="activeMenu($event)">
          <span jhiTranslate="khanbankCpmsApp.project.grantTitle">Зээлт олголт</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" [routerLink]="['facility']" [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : ''" (click)="activeMenu($event)">
          <span jhiTranslate="khanbankCpmsApp.project.facilityTitle">Зээлт олголт</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="#" [routerLink]="['compliance']" [ngClass]="status ? 'active' : ''" (click)="activeMenu($event)">
          <span jhiTranslate="khanbankCpmsApp.project.complianceTitle">Зээлт олголт</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  <router-outlet name="popup"></router-outlet>
</div>
```

But when i click the link it sets the `active` class every link. In my .ts file:

```
status: boolean = false;

activeMenu(event){
    this.status = !this.status;
    event.stopPropagation();   
}
```

What did i do wrong ? Any advice ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Bootstrap**

> npm i bootstrap
>
> add the below line inside the angular.json file: projects -> architect
>   -> styles "styles": [
>                 "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
>                 "src/styles.css"
>               ]

***user routerLinkActive="active"***

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active"
            [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
          <a routerLink="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active">
          <a routerLink="servers">Servers</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"
            routerLinkActive="active">
          <a [routerLink]="['users']">Users</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `routerLinkActive` instead.

```
<a href="#" [routerLink]="['../', project.id]" [routerLinkActive]="active" (click)="activeMenu($event)">
```

Reference: [RouterLinkActive](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive)

Answer (score 2):

on each link you have

```
[ngClass]="status ? 'active': ''"
```

if you set status to true, it will update every ngClass

try to use

```
[routerLinkActive]='active'
```

or inject to component ActivatedRoute
and do sth like

```
this.activatedRoute.url.subscribe(url => this.currentUrl = url);
```

and in template

```
[ngClass]="this.currentUrl.includes(router-link-path)? 'active' : ''"
```

don't forget to unsubscribe

i can't comment so i replay here

according to [how to set active class on elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56625976/how-to-set-active-class-on-elements/56626121#comment99825071_56626050)

your first route is

```
''
```

so it'll always be active on startup

Answer (score 0):

That's because you use the same boolean for all the elements. There is only one `status` for your entire component and you use it for every `<a>` elements.

Try to add the class only on the clicked element like so:

#### .ts:

```js
activeMenu(event){
    event.target.classList.add("className")
}
```

Using this approach, you can remove the `status` boolean from your component and the `[ngClass]` in your template

You could also use template variable on each `<a>` element or you could use routing like some other answers mentionned (since your example is only for `<a>` elements that use routerLink).
In your case `routerLinkActive` is probably the best approach

Hope that helps :)